# Excel Function to split cells

Tags: excel

If we do not use VBA, any methods can be used to split the following cell in excel?

Please advise the methods for splitting text "ParisFrancePeter" to 3 separate words "Paris" "France" and "Peter".

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe this would help (separate by capital letter: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3336-excel-split-text-by-capital-letter.html)

Comment: This reads awfully much like a test or homework question.

Answer (score 0):

```
'first word
=REPLACE(A1, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(2:99)/(CODE(MID(A1, ROW(2:99), 1))<=90), 1), LEN(A1), "")
'middle word
=MID(A1, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(2:99)/(CODE(MID(A1, ROW(2:99), 1))<=90), 1), LEN(A1)-AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW(2:99)/(CODE(MID(A1, ROW(2:99), 1))<=90), 1)+2)
'last word
=REPLACE(A1, 1, AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW(2:99)/(CODE(MID(A1, ROW(2:99), 1))<=90), 1)-1, "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you also have other than three words to split, then, with your original string in A1, enter the formula below in B1 and fill right as far as required:

```
=IFERROR(MID($A1,IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((CODE(MID($A1,seq,1))>=65)*(CODE(MID($A1,seq,1))<=90))*(seq),COLUMNS($A:A)),""),IF(IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((CODE(MID($A1,seq,1))>=65)*(CODE(MID($A1,seq,1))<=90))*(seq),COLUMNS($A:B)),"")="",99,IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((CODE(MID($A1,seq,1))>=65)*(CODE(MID($A1,seq,1))<=90))*(seq),COLUMNS($A:B)),"")-IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((CODE(MID($A1,seq,1))>=65)*(CODE(MID($A1,seq,1))<=90))*(seq),COLUMNS($A:A)),""))),"")
```

where `seq` is a **Named Formula** that generates an array of numbers `{1...255}` and  refers to:

```
  =ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))
```

The code will return the starting point of each Upper Case letter, and then uses the `MID` function to return the substring between that and the next upper case letter.  Then there is some error checking.

[image]